# How to access a dialog from workmanager's worker class

Tags: android-alertdialog, android-context, android-dialogfragment, android-workmanager

I have dialog in Activity and I need to access the dialog from worker class of workManager to show the dialog.

The dialog code is in Activity:

```
companion object {

        fun showDialog(
            context: Context,
            title: String,
            timeStamp: String,
        ) {
            val dialog = Dialog(context)
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            dialog.setCancelable(false)
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_layout)
            val closeImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_close) as ImageView
            val tvTimeStamp = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_timeStamp) as TextView
            val llAlertMain = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ll_alert_main) as LinearLayout
            tvTimeStamp.text = timeStamp
            
            closeImage.setOnClickListener {
                dialogIsShowing = false
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            dialog.show()
            dialogIsShowing = true
        }

    }
```

The worker class code:

```
override fun doWork(): Result {

        try {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
                showDialog()
            }
            return Result.success()

        }catch (e : Exception){
            return Result.failure()
        }

    }

private showDialog(){
        try {
            MainActivity.showDialog(applicationContext, title, timeStamp)
            //CustomDialogFragment.newInstance("Title", "SubTitle").show(supportFragmentManager, CustomNotificationDialogFragment.TAG)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

but it is giving error :  Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a design:

MVVM for example.

The Activity is the View. It will observe via LiveData updates from the ViewModel. The event will be: "show the dialog".

Then you create some shared object. Observable pattern. You send updates to this shared object from the Worker.

You observe the shared object via the ViewModel and from there you update the LiveData.